# Экранирование одинарных кавычек

Tags: c#

Как туда правильно впихнуть одинарную кавычку ?

```
char simbol = '''
```

Comment: @JaponDemon потому я и спрашиваю)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как и всегда:

```
char simbol = '\'';
```

Answer (score 2):

Использовать [экранирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) или апостроф:

```
char symbol = '\'';
char symbol = '`';
```